# How to measure JavaScript code coverage when executed from Java runtime

Tags: javascript, java, code-coverage, rhino, nashorn

We are migrating from Java 6 to Java 8. The application has about 1900+ JavaScript functions, which are running on Java 6 JS engine (*Rhino*). There are few JS functions like "*println()*", "*String -> replace()*" behave differently in Java 6 and Java 8. Compiling the JS code doesn't catch this semantic difference; but executing JS code does.
We need to write regression test suite for run all JS code and measure "JavaScript" code coverage to ensure all statements are working. This is going to be tricky as JavaScript code is complied to Java byte code by Java JS engine.

My question is:

**1) How to measure JavaScript code coverage when executed from Java runtime?**

We researched and couldn't find any lib/tool for this.

We are also looking for alternative approach: decompile compiled-JavaScript-bytecode to Java and feed that Java source to any Java-code-coverage-tool. (Not sure if this approach is even feasible; but want to give it a try)

So my next question is:

**2) How to convert JavaScript-compiled-bytecode to Java source?**

Comment: _"JS functions like "println()""_ -- what? JS doesn't have a `println` function...

Comment: I'm not sure the script engine compiles JavaScript to bytecode. Afaik it's just an engine that interprets javascript, with a few implementation tricks that make it easier to optimize by the JIT.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, println() in not a valid JavaScript function; but it works in JavaScript executed in Java 6/7 -> Rhino; whereas Java 8 -> Nashorn doesn't support it. It supports print() though.